# Enable field function triggers after second function is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I need some help with sequencing (not sure if this is the right term) two jQuery functions so that both can co-exist together.

What I am trying to do is to add a new functionality that makes a field uneditable to the users, like `disabled="disabled"`. Catch is that if I only apply `disabled="disabled"` to the filed the form will not send its value with the form submit.

Therefore, I have written some JS code, which enables the fields prior submitting and permits that their values are sent when form is submitted.

All works fine once the page is loaded.

Problem is when the user leaves one of the mandatory fields blank and tries to submit the form. Then there is another jQuery that fires - to validate the field contents.

This second validation function triggers the enable field function and all fields become editable again.

Need some help on how to prevent the second function to override the enable one.

Here is the code - the enable function is placed right before the form like this:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {    
    $('form').bind('submit', function() {
        $(this).find(':input').removeAttr('disabled');
    });

});
 </script>     

    <form name="RegFrm" id="RegFrm" action="" method="post">
          <select class="validate[required] text-input" disabled="disabled">
              <option value="">Please Select</option>
          </select>
          <input name="sbtFrm" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

And here is the second field validation function that is placed on a separate file. It is being invoked from files_include.php every time the page loads:

```
var genVar = jQuery.noConflict();
    genVar(document).ready(function(){
        genVar("#RegFrm").validationEngine();
    });
```

How can I prevent the second function triggers the first one?

Thank you?

Comment: Just put code at the end of the validation which disables the fields again? It seems an inherent problem since you are removing the disabled - attribute while submitting.

Comment: tried that already but it doesn't work :(

Comment: `$(this).find(':input').removeAttr('disabled');` This seems like it is *removing* the `disabled` attribute, thereby enabling the fields, once the submit button is clicked? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @CalvinScherle I think that's the point. The fields are disabled so the user cannot change them. Upon submit they get re-enabled and so that they are submitted with the form.
@BradG Try using `.prop('disabled', false)` instead of removeAttr and then after the validation `.prop('disabled', true)`there is some issue with completely removing properties that you cannot reenable them with jQuery.

Comment: I see, I guess the following sentence "I have written some JS code, which disables the wanted fields from editing and their values are still sent" confused me, implying that he had gotten the data to send even while the fields were disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the comments. Although, no solution proposed you guys gave me an idea how to fix it.

I basically decided to check on form submit if form validates and only if true, then the enable function triggers.

This is the code:

```
jQuery(function($) {    
    $('form').bind('submit', function() {
        if($("#RegFrm").validationEngine('validate')){
            $(this).find(':input').removeAttr('disabled');
        };
    });

});
```